# What is the best way to display a table if an array is not null in PHP?

Tags: php

If the array is not null (and has values in it), then I want to display the table.
But if it is null, then I don't want to display any table code at all.

Using an MVC framework which appends a footer to the page.

What is the best way to avoid a statement like:

```
<?php 
  if ($users) {
    echo '<table id="tha_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
         <tbody>';
  } ?>
```

And, don't want to do another test to add the table footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check whether an array is empty. Empty will also check whether the variable is null. Note that empty() does not throw a warning if the array variable is not set, which may or may not be desirable.

```
<?php

   $displayUserTable = !empty($users);

?>

<?php if($displayUserTable): ?>

<table id="tha_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<thead>
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user['firstName']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user['lastName']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user['emailAddress']); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</tbody>

</table>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($displayUserTable): ?>

    <!-- show footer here... -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what you are after...
I would place all of the HTML in a separate file, and conditionally include it.

```
if(!empty($users)) {
  include "users_table.template";
}
```

Note that the template file can include php if you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use either a templating system or any other vehicle to separate your PHP code from the HTML rendering.

All template systems I know of allow for a block to be skipped depending on a boolean, so you would just include the (template for the) table in your page template and surround it with whatever your chosen framework uses as an `if` or `repeat n times` construct.